# React API this.props.message.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function, api, redux, axios

I use the API to get Quotes, but I get an Unhandled Rejection error "(TypeError): this.props.message.map is not a function" https://ibb.co/dWqhjXK, I used debugger checked props saw that I get answers https://ibb.co/wM3mLb9 what then could be the reason? why am i getting this error? here is my code

**Message.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Message extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const list = this.props.message.map((item, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>
                <p>{item.content}</p>
            </div>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{list}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**MessageContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Message} from "./Message";
import {getMessageThunk} from "../../redux/message-reducer";

class MessageContainer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getMessageThunk();
    }

    render() {
        return <Message {...this.props} />
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    message: state.message.users
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getMessageThunk})(MessageContainer);
```

**message-reducer.js**

```
import {messageAPI} from "../Api/Api";

const MESSAGE = 'MESSAGE';

let initialState = {
    users: [],
};

export const messageReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case MESSAGE: {
            return {...state, users: action.users}
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const messageCreator = (users) => {
    return {
        type: MESSAGE, users
    }
};

export const getMessageThunk = (users) => (dispatch) => {
    messageAPI.getMessageAPI(users).then(response => {
        dispatch(messageCreator(response.data));
    })

}
```

**Api.js**

```
import * as axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    url: 'https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/',
    headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'bf490d72a0msh3bf159a87e0c27fp107a51jsn062ca1b9b00e',
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'quotes15.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
});


export const messageAPI = {
    getMessageAPI() {
        return instance.get(`https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/`)
    },
};
```

Comment: Looking at it I cannot give you a direct answer but it seems like message is either not of type Array. You could try to check it in the debugger to see if it is defined and is an array.

Comment: Do you want me to edit my question and link my project to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message is not an array but an object. You do not have anything to iterate over there you could either simply return `this.props.message.content` but this is not a list.

```js
 const item = <p>{this.props.message.content}</p>
```